# Im using ZF2 in my ongoing project it gives network error on singup

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, redis

I'm new in this framework, this project is developed with redis and mysql but the console is not giving database connectivity error. It is pointing towards the following code having network error in console.log() which is in utils.js

```
function log(TAG, str) 
{
    if (debug) {
        if ($.inArray(TAG, enabled) != -1)
            console.log(TAG + ":" + str); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give us the exact error? Where do you call this log-function? Btw till now the mysql, php and redis tags are unnecessary.

Comment: "Utils:JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

Comment: no other error is showing

Comment: function handleResponse(data)
{
 var cookie = Utils.cookie("origUri");
 Utils.log(TAG + cookie);
 Router.switchTo("app");
}

function clearStatus()
{
 $status.html("");
}

return {init: init};

});

Comment: in signin.js call the tags